# Trouble storing a struct in an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to create a database sort of, that stores a list of 5000 names and 5000 coresponding salaries into an array, I simply can't find the problem since the console either crashes or the compiler gives me the following error: "cannot convert 'char* (*)[30]' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char*' fgets(char*,int,*FILE)".

EDIT: I changed whatever I could figure out in the code, and I seem to have an issue with
this line in particular:

```
person* TAB = calloc(N, sizeof(struct));
```

I can't spot other errors(lack of experience), and I don't know exactly what to use instead of fgets to put in a line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5000
typedef struct {
  char name[30]
  int  salary;
} person;
int main()
{
person* TAB = calloc(N, sizeof(struct));
FILE * input;
input = fopen("in.txt","r+");
int nr=0;
int r;
while(nr<5000)
    {
      fscanf(input,"%s",TAB[nr].name);
      fscanf(input,"%d",TAB[nr].salary);
      nr++;
    }
printf("%s %d",TAB[1].name,TAB[1].salary);
fclose(input);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't tag as C++ things that have not absolutely to do with C++

Comment: Ahh...lots of issues/errors

Comment: Your first problem is `char* name[30]`. That is an array of 30 pointers to char not an array of 30 chars.

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid putting that much data on the stack, which is what a normal variable like that will generally do. It will occupy around 5000 * (30 + 4 * 5000) = 95 MB of stack space, which might be more than your operating system  feels is reasonable.

Anyway, the fix is not to allocate this on the heap; the fix is to change the declaration. I believe there's a logic error, since you allocate space for 5000 salaries *per person*, which is probably not what you meant.

Also, the `name` field should be an array of characters, but you've declared it as an array of character *pointers*, which is what the warnings are all about.

I believe you should have:

```
struct person
{
    char name[30];
    int  salary;
};
```

This will drop the memory usage for `struct person TAB[N];` down to around 5000 * (30 + 4) or around 166 KB which is way more reasonable. This assumes a 4-byte `int` which is a pretty common situation.

Finally, your file reading code is not very nicely designed, it will probably not work.

Look into using `fgets()` to read lines, stopping when it fails (i.e. never calling `feof()`), and then parsing/tokenizing each line as read. Remember that names can contain whitespace, which will make `%s` in `sscanf()` stop.

Comment: I just noticed that, I guess for some reason I slipped that there.

Answer (score 1):

The name struct member should not be declared as 30 char pointers and the salary is one per name so it should look something like this

```
typedef struct {
  char name[30]
  int  salary;
} person;
```

Now in order to have it as an array you are best off allocating on the heap

```
person* persons = calloc(N, sizeof(struct));
```

Now you can access the name and salary of one person

```
persons[3].name
persons[3].salary

...

fgets(persons[nr].name,30,input); // although you may want to remove \n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct person
{
    char* name[30];
```

I think you mean `char name[30]`.  That is if you want *one* name of at most 29 bytes.

Later on you do:

```
fgets(&TAB[nr].name,30,input);
```

Why are you taking the address?  If you make the change above, the `TAB[nr].name` should be of type `char[30]`, which should degenerate into a `char*` as desired.